using cycles render cause specical areas darker
this is cycle render, then it cause the leg color mismatching and darker.

and this is the eevee one, render well



Duplicate 3D mesh overlap gives this errors,cycles can't handle this sitution, so i need to remove the overlap face.

To remove overlapping faces is always a good idea to get better geometry, not only if you are using Cycles.
